# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'writer'

Tags: python, opencv, export-to-csv

This program is to draw bounding box by click and drag on the image and prints the bounding box coordinates and I.m getting this error saying
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'writer'

```
    import cv2
    import csv
    
    class BoundingBoxWidget(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.original_image = cv2.imread('data/colorpic3.jpg')
            self.clone = self.original_image.copy()
    
            cv2.namedWindow('image')
            cv2.setMouseCallback('image', self.extract_coordinates)
    
            # Bounding box reference points
            self.image_coordinates = []
    
        def extract_coordinates(self, event, x, y, flags, parameters):
            # Record starting (x,y) coordinates on left mouse button click
            if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
                self.image_coordinates = [(x,y)]
    
            # Record ending (x,y) coordintes on left mouse button release
            elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
                self.image_coordinates.append((x,y))
              
           with open('results.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
                 writer= csv.writer(csvfile)

                 writer.writerow(['top left: {}, bottom right: {}'.format(self.image_coordinates[0], self.image_coordinates[1])])
                 writer.writerow(['x,y,w,h : ({}, {}, {}, {})'.format(self.image_coordinates[0][0], self.image_coordinates[0][1], self.image_coordinates[1][0] - self.image_coordinates[0][0], self.image_coordinates[1][1] - self.image_coordinates[0][1])])     
                
                # Draw rectangle 
                cv2.rectangle(self.clone, self.image_coordinates[0], self.image_coordinates[1], (0,255,0), 2)
                cv2.imshow("image", self.clone) 
    
            # Clear drawing boxes on right mouse button click
            elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
                self.clone = self.original_image.copy()
    
    
    
    
                
    
        def show_image(self):
            return self.clone
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        boundingbox_widget = BoundingBoxWidget()
        while True:
            cv2.imshow('image', boundingbox_widget.show_image())
            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    
            # Close program with keyboard 'q'
            if key == ord('q'):
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                exit(1)
```

Here I'm trying to store bounding box coordinates directly to csv file and getting this error.Instead of print statement I'm using csv writer to store those values.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually show us the parts that caused the error, but I can guess what you did.

You have an `import csv`, which you did not show us, but you also import pandas, and at some point you did:

```
csv = pd.read_csv(...)
```

That ERASES the imported module, and binds the name `csv` to your DataFrame.  Thus, when you go to use the `csv` module, it isn't there.

Use a different name for your `csv` dataframe and all will be well.

Comment: Sorry for that,  I have already imported csv module and forget to add it in  question and I have used cv2 for importing the image

Comment: The error part is in line 18 when I use print statement instead of csv writer it's working fine but if I use csv writer I get this error

Comment: Yes, I know.  I told you exactly why it happens.  You are still not showing us everything.  You tagged pandas, and the error message is from pandas, but there's no pandas code here.  You must change the name of your DataFrame.  It's just that simple.

Comment: I'm sorry for tagging pandas, the issue here is I don't use pandas in this program and I get this error related to pandas

Comment: Are you using Jupyter?  Perhaps you have a symbol leftover from before.  There is no question from the error message, your `csv` global is a pandas DataFrame, not an imported module.

Comment: Thanks, I was using vs code and after editing I didn't save the code and  it resolved